# To deploy a web application outside webapps folder in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'd like to deploy a web application in folder

```
C:\webApp
```

to Tomcat7.x instead of having a copy under

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%\webapps
```

Which configuration is required on tomcat server?

Answer (score 2):

```
 1. Create a file name <yourapp>.xml inside location    ${CATALINE_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost

 2. Add the below content in the xml file created above

<Context displayName="yourapp" 
     docBase="/path/to/yourapp"
     path="/yourapp"
     reloadable="true" />

3. Restart tomcat
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Tomcat configuration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) which shows you how to do this.

> [Contexts can be defined in] individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's META-INF directory.

The `context.xml` file in this case must include a `<Context>` element with a `docBase` attribute pointing to the WAR file (or exploded WAR directory) where your application resides on the disk (in your case: `C:\webApp`).

Comment: In the case of windows, which format will have the path?? c:\webapp, c:\\webApp, c:/webApp??